# Seeking OpenJump tool for point/node conflation/matching?

Tags: openstreetmap, software-recommendations, openjump, conflation

Are there any OpenJump tools for **conflating** (matching) two layers of **point** (node) data?

I'm particularly interested in using such a tool to sync data with **OpenStreetMap**, where I've created a [wiki page on the subject of conflation.](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Conflation) That page links to some university research projects on the conflation of vector datasets using **OpenJUMP**, however they don't share their work.

I know algorithmically this task shouldn't be that difficult especially compared to handling generic vectors, as it would simply use **distance** and similar **properties** along with some math, however I suppose I'm more interested in a **graphical interface** implemented in open source software.

**I wrote up a possible workflow for conflating nodes** [here on the OSM wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Conflation/Nodes). I thought of trying to implement it in [JOSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JOSM).

I think it might be useful to say what use cases I'd be interested in using this tool for.

- Syncing Virginia interstate exit data from VDOT with OSM
- Syncing [GNIS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/USGS_GNIS) feature points with OSM

After an extension to conflate polygons (using their centroids), the tool could also be used for:

- Transferring properties (tags, attributes) between nodes representing a house along with addressing data to a polygon (area, closed way) of the actual building

I'm sure there are many other possibilities, but these are the few I'm planning to use  it for.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if you've researched the automated conflation software called MapMerger (offered by ESEA, in California). Their conflation tool automates much of the matching process, and includes a robust set of manual matching and editing tools. And it has a great UI. It's an ArcMap extension.

Comment: I reduced the scope of this question to prevent it being too broad.  The QGIS aspects are already present in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206595/qgis-conflation-tool which I trimmed in a complementary way to prevent it being too broad too.

Answer (score 6):

Probably you have seen the [JCS Conflation Suite](http://www.vividsolutions.com/JCS/) but in case you didn't, it works with Jump.

> The JCS Conflation Suite is an API and set of interactive tools which
>   perform conflation on spatial datasets.

Comment: I've heard of the Java Topology Suite (JTS), but not the Java Conflation Suite (JCS), though it appears JCS uses JTS. JCS hasn't been updated since 2003, so it likely will require some work to get it running with the most recent OpenJUMP edition. I've created a [repository at Github](https://github.com/joshdoe/jcs) using the 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 releases from Vivid Solutions. Is anyone using JCS these days?

Comment: I should add that I've also come across RoadMatcher, an OpenJUMP plugin based on JCS for conflating roads. I'd like to get to that eventually, but for now the node conflation would be more readily useful. I haven't gotten JCS working yet, but it doesn't appear to offer the kind of node conflation I'm looking for. Perhaps this process is not called conflation? The JCS docs all talk about conflating polygons and edges (ways).