# How can I assign road names from OSM to gis linestrings using open source tools?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, open-source-gis, algorithm

Starting with a shapefile of linestrings I want to assign street names to these lines if there is a match with a road/street in OpenStreetMap.

There are no exact matches as the linestrings have a different source. It could be that some linestrings have no counterpart in the OSM data or that some linestrings are longer than the roads in OSM in which case I will probably have to cut my own linestrings to be able to name them properly.

I love to hear a complete solution, but tips and hints are also welcome.

Comment: [These people](http://code.google.com/p/tamt/wiki/MapMatchingAlgorithm) discuss the idea of matching each individual point on the linestring to the road it is on.

Comment: Conflation tools are what you need -- 
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8262/open-source-tool-for-point-node-conflation-matching

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Conflation

Colleagues have used Map Merger http://www.mapmerger.com/  with some success, but there is license cost.